# shortest highway problem

Tags: geometry

Two cities are form different sides of a river.  A highway connecting A and B needs to be built so the of the highway is on a bridge XY perpendicular to the parallel banks of the river.  Where should the bridge be built so that AXYB is as short as possible.

Details and assumptions :

The bridge has to be perpendicular to the river bank

The river banks are parallel

I believe that I could project YB up so that X and Y coincide.  Then by connecting point A to B', I would take the new intersection point of this line and the bank of the river.  This point would be one of the locations where the bridge should be built so that AXYB is as short as possible.  I just don't know how to put all this into mathematical terms.

Comment: Is the river straight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that the banks of the river are parallel.

[image]

From city A, draw a line AA’ that is equal and parallel to the width of the river. Such an act can successfully “virtually move” city A to location A’.

The shortest distance between the 2 cities is now A’B (the green line).

This line somehow will cut the river bank at Y.

From Y, build the perpendicular bridge YX.

The highway is now AX + XY + YB.

Comment: The logic equally applies when we start from city B, but we will end up with the same highway.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematical terms, the length of the bridge is invariant among all paths, so may be ignored.  If the river were of width zero, then the shortest distance between $A$ and $B$ is the straight line between them.  Now leave those roads where they are and make the river wider, inserting a bridge.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I somehow have to apply the triangle inequality theorem.

Comment: Mathematical circles the russian expereince? 
If so the solution does not mention the traingle inequality