# Determining the position of a perpendicular line segment connecting two parallel lines that is equidistant from 2 points

Tags: geometry

I was given this problem and I can't seem to think of a solution.

Here is a possibly helpful graphic:

[image: Here is a possibly helpful link:]

> Given two parallel lines (representing the banks of a river) and two arbitrary points $A$ and $B$ outside of the river (one above the top parallel line and one below the bottom parallel line). A bridge is to be constructed connecting the two sides of the river at point $P$ and $Q$  are to be an equal distance between points $A$ and $B$, i.e. $\overline{AP}$ = $\overline{BQ}$.
>
> Where should the bridge be placed, assuming that it runs at right angles to the banks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shortest highway problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809387/shortest-highway-problem)

Comment: @MikePierce This is not a duplicate because [shortest highway problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809387/shortest-highway-problem) is minimizing the distance whereas this is trying to make AX and BY equal segments

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry about that. I have heard this problem before, though (it's mildly well known), so I think it must have been asked on this site before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a method for constructing the point $P$.

Construct the point $B_1$ obtained by translating point $B$ by the vector $\overrightarrow{QP}$. This can be done even without knowing the position of $P$ and $Q$, because the direction of the vector is perpendicular to the river (towards the side $A$ is on) and its length is the width of the river.

Now the problem is how to select $P$ so that $AP = PB_1$. The point $P$ is to be selected equidistant from $A$ and $B_1$, hence it must be on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $AB_1$. Construct $P$ as the intersection of the upper line with the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB_1$.

Comment: @Kevin I rejected the proposed edit to my answer in part because I really mean $AP = PB_1$, not $\overrightarrow{AP} = \overrightarrow{PB_1}$. I'm talking about the lengths, not the vectors.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I guess I misinterpreted the $\overline{AP}$ in assuming that it meant length

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short geometric approach:

[image: representation]

Approach bottom line to the other line *with* the point $B$. Draw a segment from $A$ to $B$. Find the middle point $C$ of this segment. Draw perpendicular from $C$ to your river and find intersection. That's the point you looking for.

Comment: Can you do this assuming the distance between the river is nonzero, i.e. P and Q are not the same point?

Comment: @Kevin, do you mean without the iteration? Sure. Draw perpendicular from $B$ to the river and find $B'$ such that $|BB'|=|PQ|$. Then do above process for upper line with $B'$ instead of $B$.

Comment: Thanks @Alistair! and yes that is what I meant.